# Automate Sending Payments to bank accounts

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments, payment, payment-processing

I need to find the best solution for automated payments into bank accounts. My scenario is that we have funds in a bank account(which can be registered a provider account like paypal or stripe if needed).

When a user submits a request for money, i need to automatically send that amount to their bank account from our bank account(or payment provider account).
Is there a way to automate? it needs to be able to support most european bank accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Through PayPal, there is not a way to do that with the request money feature. The request money feature is there for the specific purpose of requesting money from a particular user. If you were able to do that, then there wouldn't be stopping someone from constantly requesting money from you and you just pay them whatever that amount is.

I would assume this is also not possible with Stripe, because having this capability is a HUGE risk on the merchant and payment processor end.

A better way to do it, is by using [Mass Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mass-pay/integration-guide/MassPayOverview/?mark=mass%20payment) through PayPal to schedule payments to a mass number of users. This does require approval from PayPal, so you will need to contact them to get it enabled.

Comment: i believe that the Paypal Mass Payment requires the receiving users to also have paypal which in my case, they might not.

Comment: Stripe offer a beta for UK users called Managed Accounts, which kind of covers what i'm trying to do, only problem is its a beta at this moment.

Comment: Yes that's correct, the Mass Pay does require receivers to have a paypal account. All the transactions in paypal have to hit their account first before it can be withdrawn.

Comment: Did i understand that correctly? You want it to where if a buyer just requests money from you, you automatically pay them? I cant imagine that you would want something like that. I mean technically you could have a script to scan your email and then make an API call to pay that buyer.

Comment: I don't want to be bound to the user having a paypal account, because we receive payments from multiple sources, bank transfer, stripe and paypal. Ideally, a system which offers an automated way to make bank transfers is what i am looking for

Comment: Ah ok, I thought you were just paying anyone who asked you for money haha. Well if that is the case, then yea you can set up auto sweep in your PayPal account to automatically withdraw your funds each night. Here is a good post on it: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/PayPal-Mobile-Other-Services/how-do-I-turn-auto-sweep-on/td-p/372380

Comment: no you were right, i want to pay anyone who asks for money(essentially) and they might not have paypal accounts